# if content overflow show more, default hidden

Tags: html, css

Default hide the show button, if content is overflow show show more button

```html
<div class="q-list-box">
  <div class="q-list-heading">
    <p>Formulas and Percentage on Averages</p>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-2" />
  <ul class="read-more-wrap circle">
    <li>Question no 1 - Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Question no 2 - Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Question no 3 - Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Question no 4 - Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Question no 5 - Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li class="read-more-target">Question no 6 - Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li class="read-more-target">Question no 7 - Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li class="read-more-target">Question no 8 - Lorem Ipsum</li>
  </ul>
  <label for="post-2" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't understand

Comment: @NayasSubramanian have a look jsfiddle

Comment: @NayasSubramanian https://jsfiddle.net/babuharry/rfj9yaj9/

Comment: ok, i will check it

Comment: i want that show more button hidden default when it the li content overflow  then i have to get show more button

Comment: ok i understood what is your requirement, let me check it

Comment: You will need javascript for this - please add additional tags (javascript, jquery..) if you are open to those solutions